# How to find buttons in a datawindow

Tags: powerbuilder

lets say there is a Datawindow with some columns and some Buttons. How can I get an Array of all Buttons inside the dw ( or better of all Controls )? For columns I can do things like

```
ll_cnt = Long(this.dw_1.object.datawindow.column.count)

for i = 1 to ll_cnt
    lsa_colname[upperbound(lsa_colname)+1]  = this.dw_1.Describe( "#" + String(i) + ".Name" )
    lsa_coltype[upperbound(lsa_coltype)+1]      =  this.dw_1.Describe( "#" + String(i) + ".ColType" )
    lsa_edittype[upperbound(lsa_edittype)+1]    =  this.dw_1.Describe( "#" + String(i) + ".Edit.Style" )
NEXT
```

Is there a similar way for other controls?

I'm Using PB12.6

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get all objects in the datawindow use this

```
<DW Control Name>.Object.DataWindow.Objects
```

or

```
<DW Control Name>.Describe("DataWindow.Objects")
```

both returns a TAB separated list of all objects. 
eg. `emp_name~temp_street~tlabel_emp_name~tlabel_emp_street`

from there on you can extract all the names of objects from the returned string. To get the type of the objects use

```
<DW Control Name>.Describe("<objectname>.Type")
```

eg.

```
dw_1.Describe("emp_name.Type")
```

dot-notation doesn't work here if you do not know the objectnames during coding.

For PB8 and later (maybe PB7 but I only know for PB8 and above) you can click NEW in the IDE and from the opened window choose tools and than datawindow syntax.Than you get all possible dw-properties with the syntax for describe/modify and dot notation